# PHP POST form validating error

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I've got a PHP form that executes on the contact form's page. I've got it working well - but it currently only checks to make sure name and email are entered. I'm trying to get it to check for a message too, but my attempts just cos the page not to load after the php. Here's what I have:

```
<?php 
 $to = "me@gmail.com" ; 
 $from = $_REQUEST['Email'] ; 
 $name = $_REQUEST['Name'] ; 
 $headers = "From: $from"; 
 $subject = "Web Contact Data";
 $startmonth = $_REQUEST['StartMonth'];
 $startyear = $_REQUEST['StartYear'];
 $endmonth = $_REQUEST['EndMonth'];
 $endyear = $_REQUEST['EndYear'];
 $message = $_REQUEST['Message'];

 $fields = array(); 
 $fields{"Name"} = "Name"; 
 $fields{"Email"} = "Email"; 
 $fields{"Phone"} = "Phone"; 

 $selectedProjects  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['projects']) && is_array($_POST['projects']) && count($_POST['projects']) > 0){
    $selectedProjects = implode(', ', $_POST['projects']);
}
 $selectedSkills  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['skills']) && is_array($_POST['skills']) && count($_POST['skills']) > 0){
    $selectedSkills = implode(', ', $_POST['skills']);
}
$selectedNoRush  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['norush']) && is_array($_POST['norush']) && count($_POST['norush']) > 0){
    $NoRush= implode(', ', $_POST['norush']);
}
$selectedWhenReady  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['whenready']) && is_array($_POST['whenready']) && count($_POST['whenready']) > 0){
    $WhenReady= implode(', ', $_POST['whenready']);
}
$selectedBudget  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['budget']) && is_array($_POST['budget']) && count($_POST['budget']) > 0){
    $selectedBudget= implode(', ', $_POST['budget']);
} 

$body = "We have received the following information:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){$body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]);}
$body .= "\n" . 'Selected Projects: ' . $selectedProjects . "\n";
$body .= 'Selected Skills: ' . $selectedSkills . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Start Date: ' . $startmonth . " " . $startyear . " " . $NoRush . "\n";
$body .= 'End Date: ' . $endmonth . " " . $endyear . " " . $WhenReady . "\n";
$body .= 'Budget: ' . $selectedBudget . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Message:' . $message . "\n";



 $headers2 = "From: me@gmail.com"; 
 $subject2 = "Thank you for contacting us"; 
 $autoreply = "Thank you for contacting us. Somebody will get back to you as soon as possible, usually within 48 hours.";

 if($from == '') {print "You have not entered an email, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 
 if($name == '') {print "You have not entered a name, please go back and try again";} 
 else {
 $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); 
 $send2 = mail($from, $subject2, $autoreply, $headers2); 
 if($send) 
 {print "Thank you. Your request has been successfully submitted.";} 
 else 
 {print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please check your details are correct or email us at hello@lyonempire.co.uk"; } 
 }
}
 ?>
```

So the above all works fine, but when I add the following code after the name/email checks, it breaks:

```
if($message == '') {print "You have not entered a message, please go back and try again";} 
 else {
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks! MC

Comment: That's the most unusual bracketing style I've recently seen...

Comment: `it breaks`. In what way does it break? What message do you get? Exactly how does your code look with the lines included (just show the new lines and two lines before and after instead of only the new lines)

Comment: @rr this is my first go at PHP code - please let me know why it is unusual because I'm piecing it together and it would really help to know...

Comment: @Arjan the rest of the page stopped loading and the form and footer didn't load. It was a missing curly bracket, because I am an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i cant tell from the code you've shown, but have you closed the curly bracket on your else statement?

```
if($message == '') {print "You have not entered a message, please go back and try again";} 
else {} <----
```

Comment: That's it, I feel stupid.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($name == '')
{
    print "You have not entered a name, please go back and try again";
}
else if($message == '') {
    // do what ever you want
} 
else {
    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); 
    $send2 = mail($from, $subject2, $autoreply, $headers2);
```

.... Rest goes here